# Terraform templatefile function error when running with array in template

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file, terraform-template

I have the following code:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13.1"
}

resource "local_file" "plan" {
  content  = templatefile("plan-pipeline-template.tftpl", var.generatedvars)
  filename = "${path.module}/plan-generated"
}
```

my plan-pipeline-template.tftpl file is:

```
%{ for var in ${VAR_PATHS} ~}
${var}-plan:
%{ endfor ~}
```

in order to provide the generatedvars which is being used by main.tf, i run the following:

```
export TF_VAR_generatedvars='{VAR_PATHS=["aaa","vvv"]}'
```

but it doesn't work, and i get:

```
Error: Error in function call

  on main.tf line 6, in resource "local_file" "plan":
   6:   content  = templatefile("plan-pipeline-template.tftpl", var.generatedvars)
    |----------------
    | var.generatedvars is map of tuple with 1 element

Call to function "templatefile" failed:
plan-pipeline-template.tftpl:1,15-16:
Invalid character; This character is not used within the language., and 1
other diagnostic(s).
```

if i change my *plan-pipeline-template.tftpl* with a hardcoded array, it works:

```
%{ for var in ["jj","kk"] ~}
${var}-plan:
%{ endfor ~}
```

which generates

```
jj-plan
kk-plan
```

any idea what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
%{ for var in ${VAR_PATHS} ~}
```

seems like i don't need to use **${VAR_PATHS}** instead, i should just use *VAR_PATHS*, because it is already considered as a variable inside a %{for...} loop.

This should work:

```
%{ for var in VAR_PATHS ~}
```

Comment: That's actually correct. It's exactly how it is explained in the documentation: https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile#lists